# Annihilators of powers of the maximal ideal in an Artinian Gorenstein ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, gorenstein, artinian

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a commutative Artinian Gorenstein ring. Let $n$ be such that $\mathfrak{m}^n\neq0=\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$. I see that $\mathfrak{m}^n=(0:\mathfrak{m})$, is it true that $\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}=(0:\mathfrak{m}^2)$? And more generally $\mathfrak{m}^{n-i}=(0:\mathfrak{m}^{i+1})$?

Comment: Try $R=K[[X,Y,Z]]/(XY,XZ,YZ,X^3-Y^2,X^3-Z^2)$. Is $\mathfrak m^2=(0:\mathfrak m^2)$?

Comment: I see, $\mathfrak{m}^2=(x^2)$ and $y\in(0:\mathfrak{m}^2)$ but $y\not\in\mathfrak{m}^2$. Thank you for your example.